# Linux syslog says "ata11: link is slow to respond" for my new HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, drivers, sata

I built a new machine with the following hardware (at least the relevant parts):

- Asus P8P67 Deluxe
- Western Digital Caviar Green 2 TB Desktop Hard Drive WD20EARX
- 750W Power Supply (so there's plenty of juice)

Last night I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04, but kept seeing the error message:

ata9.01: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)

That HDD is a 6Gb/s SATA. The P8P67 has two different SATA controllers: an Intel (3 Gb/s and 6Gb/s ports) and a Marvell (6 Gb/s ports only). I tried plugging the drive into each controller and got the same results from both.

I pulled an old 1.5 Gb/s SATA drive out of an old machine, and this works fine plugged into a 3Gb/s port -- installation succeeded and the machine is running ok.

After installing onto the old drive, I tried plugging the new drive into the 3Gb/s Intel controller, with the same message when I try to format the drive.

The drive *is* detected, SMART (including the short self test) says it is healthy, and it looks like the partition table was at least partially written because the swap partition is there from when I tried to install onto it.

Some web searches indicated that the problem might be with AHCI, I went into BIOS and turned off AHCI -- same error messages.

- Is the drive DOA or is this more likely to be a driver problem? Is there a way to prove it is DOA for an RMA (will I need to)?
- Is there something I can tweak in the BIOS, kernel, or driver config to make it work?

Comment: What Kernel are you using?

Comment: @BartonChittenden: The installation that succeeded identifies as `kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae`. I'm *guessing* that the installer uses this version or something close; it was just released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was DOA. Tried a couple of drives in the same slots and they worked fine, so I returned it, Amazon shipped a new one, and the new one works fine.